# PHP MySQL Insert array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, insert

I'm having trouble with inserting the values from this array. Here example:

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['dynfields'], true);
    //{"dynfields":{"dynfields[0][DescRepair]":"Desc repair","dynfields[0][NestParts]":"Parts","dynfields[0][EdPrice]":"10","dynfields[0][DateRepair]":"2015-07-20","dynfields[1][DescRepair]":"Desc repair","dynfields[1][NestParts]":"Parts","dynfields[1][EdPrice]":"5","dynfields[1][DateRepair]":"2015-07-20"}}

    foreach ($arr as $key => $fieldArray ) {
        foreach($fieldArray as $k => $v) {
            echo $k . " - " . $v . "<br>"; // result: dynfields[0][DescRepair] - Desc repair
                                            dynfields[0] [NestParts] - Parts
                                            dynfields[0][EdPrice] - 10
                                            dynfields[0][DateRepair] - 2015-07-20
                                            dynfields[1][DescRepair] - Desc repair
                                            dynfields[1][NestParts] - Parts
                                            dynfields[1][EdPrice] - 5
                                            dynfields[1][DateRepair] - 2015-07-20

        }
        //$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO repair (DescRepair, NestParts, EdPrice, DateRepair) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));  
    }
```

This is my code, but I don't know how to insert the value in db. Can you give me any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand very well your code, but at first your json is bad, on post, this is an example of right json:

```
{
"dynfields": [
    {
        "DescRepair": "Desc repair",
        "NestParts": "Parts",
        "EdPrice": "10",
        "DateRepair": "2015-07-20"
    },
    {
        "DescRepair": "Desc repair",
        "NestParts": "Parts",
        "EdPrice": "5",
        "DateRepair": "2015-07-20"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can make a foreach with the dynfields data:

```
$myvar = json_decode($json,true);
$data = $myvar['dynfields'];


    foreach(array_keys($data) as $index){
        var_dump($data[$index]);
    }
```

then you will get something like this (var_dump):

```
 array (size=4)
      'DescRepair' => string 'Desc repair' (length=11)
      'NestParts' => string 'Parts' (length=5)
      'EdPrice' => string '10' (length=2)
      'DateRepair' => string '2015-07-20' (length=10)
 array (size=4)
      'DescRepair' => string 'Desc repair' (length=11)
      'NestParts' => string 'Parts' (length=5)
      'EdPrice' => string '5' (length=1)
      'DateRepair' => string '2015-07-20' (length=10)
```

Comment: I know the json is bad structured, but I don't find another solution to get value from inputs and send to php code and make records in the database. If you have better solution I will be happy to see it https://jsfiddle.net/1ox3Ltfr/1/. Thanks.

Comment: Put your fields into a form, then when you click the show button do this:

var formData = $("#formId").serialize();

You have send this to server via AJAX and then you will received a correct array, the you can convert to JSON or not

Answer (score 0):

`$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO repair (DescRepair, NestParts, EdPrice, DateRepair) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))`

relace each `?` with `{$arr['xxxxx']}` Where xxxxx are your array keys

make sure to well-escape the variables to prevent SQL Injection

Hint: you can use PDO or prepared statements